# Product received Administrator in Odoo 8 purchase module

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-view

In social network features in odoo 8. In one, Purchase Order > In Shipments > Transfer.

After transfer, it is showing "Products received Administrator updated document"

But I want to see who has clicked "Transfer" button. I have attached screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have two options,

1. create a log note for the related record with whom clicked while clicking the transfer button.
2. this is achieved with the feature of **track_visibility**

eg:     `partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Customer', track_visibility='onchange', index=True,`

Here whenever you made change on the partner_id field will create a log note.

another value of track_visibility is 'always'

eg:

```
name = fields.Char(string='Task Title', track_visibility='always', required=True, index=True)
```

this will log values always has a data.

Lets take the first option.
make a new field which will update the flag when ever the transfer button clicks. and give the attribute track_visibility = 'onchange'.

eg: `flag = fields.Boolean(string='string', default=False, track_visibility='onchange')`

overide the function which trigger the transfer button and update the value. You can see the log note who is done the transfer.

or with the same function without the extra field you can create a log note for the record.

Comment: Sorry, 2nd approach does not work. 1st approach giving error it does not starts the server. Actually, I am very new in odoo. It will be helpful for me if you give me code example. What I have done, is. The "Transfer" button calls stock_picking's "do_enter_transfer_details" method. I just inherited the 'stock.picking' in my module. Created _columns={'partner_id': ...} it does not work. _columns={'flag': ...} shows error, server does not start. I think, I need to do something in "do_enter_transfer_details" method. But, don't know, what to do.